# Unit testcase for Optional type

Tags: java, junit, junit4, junit5

This is my original method:

```java
public Unit getUnitSymbolForCRSCode(Integer crsCode) {  
    String crsUnitName = getCrsByCode(crsCode).getUnitName();
    List<Unit> unitList = getUnits();
    Optional<Unit> unit = unitList.stream().filter(u->u.getUnitOfMeasureName().equalsIgnoreCase(crsUnitName)).findFirst();
    if(!unit.isPresent()){
        throw new DataNotFoundException(String.format("Failed to retrieve unit details for %s.",crsUnitName));
    }
    return unit.get();
}
```

While writing a test case for it like below, one branch is not covered. Im unable to get DataNotFoundException thrown.

```java
@Test
public void testGetUnitSymbolForCRSCodeThrowingDataNotFoundException() {
    Unit unitObj = new Unit();
    Mockito.when(geoCalService.search(Mockito.any(SearchFilter.class)))
        .thenReturn(TestDataFactory.getSearchResultResponseForCRS());

    Mockito.when(uomService.getUnits()).thenReturn(Arrays.asList(unitObj));
    thrown.expect(DataNotFoundException.class); 
    shellGeodeticService.getUnitSymbolForCRSCode(50015);
}
```

Im getting error like

```
java.lang.AssertionError: Expected test to throw an instance of com.shell.geodetic.exception.DataNotFoundException.
```

Though UnitObj is empty, its not throwing DataNotFoundException. Please assist.

```java
public static List<Unit> getUnitList() {
    List<Unit> unitList= new ArrayList<Unit>();
    unitList.add(new Unit("dega","Degree"));
    unitList.add(new Unit("ft[US]","US Survey foot"));
    unitList.add(new Unit("m","Meter"));
    unitList.add(new Unit("ft[Se]","Sear's Foot"));
    unitList.add(new Unit("ft[GC]","Gold Coast Foot"));
    unitList.add(new Unit("ft","International Foot"));      
    unitList.add(new Unit("link[Cla]","Clarke's Link"));
    unitList.add(new Unit("gon","Grad"));
    return unitList;
}


public CRS getCrsByCode(Integer code) {
    SearchResultResponse response = searchCode(String.valueOf(code), 180224);
    List<DisplayItem> crsDisplayItems = response.getDisplayItems();
    if (crsDisplayItems.isEmpty()) {
        throw new DataNotFoundException("CRS not found with code " + code + ": " + response.getSearchMessage());
    }
    return Util.convertToCrsVoList(crsDisplayItems).get(0);
}
```

Comment: You do need to post the `getUnits()` method. I assume it calls the `geoCalService.search()` you are mocking. Also, from your code it's not obvious you don't get back an empty or non-matching result; maybe you should define a separate test case for this, without using the `TestDataFactory`.

Comment: the getUnits code i have added. yes, it internally calls the seach() method. Also, it always returns a matching result. So i need to write a test for nonMatching result where if(!unit.isPresent()){} condition will become true and will throw DataNotFoundException

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're sending us down a rabbit hole of more and more methods that ultimately provide some data.

Here's how you generally write this kind of stuff.

```
class MyService {
    CrsService crsService;
    UnitService unitService;

public Unit getUnitSymbolForCRSCode(Integer crsCode) {  
    String crsUnitName = crsService.getCrsByCode(crsCode).getUnitName();
    return unitService.getUnits().stream()
                    .filter(u->u.getUnitOfMeasureName().equalsIgnoreCase(crsUnitName))
                    .findFirst()
                    .orElseThrow(() -> 
                                 new DataNotFoundException(String.format(
                                     "Failed to retrieve unit details for %s.",crsUnitName));
}
```

and this is how you test it (JUnit 5):

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
class MyServiceTest {
    @Mock crsService;
    @Mock unitService;
    @InjectMocks MyService;

    @Test
    void testNoDataException() {
        CRS crs = mock(CRS.class);
        when(crsService.getCrsByCode(any())).thenReturn(crs);
        when(unitService.getUnits()).thenReturn(Collections.emptyList());

        assertThrows(DataNotFoundException.class,
                     () -> sut.getUnitSymbolForCRSCode(123));
    }
}
```

For completeness' sake, this would be your `CrsService` and `UnitService` as you posted later:

```
class FixedUnitService implements UnitService {
    public List<Unit> getUnits() {
        List<Unit> unitList= new ArrayList<Unit>();
        unitList.add(new Unit("dega","Degree"));
        unitList.add(new Unit("ft[US]","US Survey foot"));
        unitList.add(new Unit("m","Meter"));
        unitList.add(new Unit("ft[Se]","Sear's Foot"));
        unitList.add(new Unit("ft[GC]","Gold Coast Foot"));
        unitList.add(new Unit("ft","International Foot"));      
        unitList.add(new Unit("link[Cla]","Clarke's Link"));
        unitList.add(new Unit("gon","Grad"));
        return unitList;
    }
}
class LookupCrsService implements CrsService {
    public Crs getCrsByCode(int id) {
        SearchResultResponse response = searchCode(String.valueOf(code), 180224);
        List<DisplayItem> crsDisplayItems = response.getDisplayItems();
        if (crsDisplayItems.isEmpty()) {
            throw new DataNotFoundException("CRS not found with code " + code + ": " + response.getSearchMessage());
        }
        return Util.convertToCrsVoList(crsDisplayItems).get(0);
    }
}
```

You can test those classes entirely separately.

Answer (score 0):

I believe, the easiest would be having a `unitList` such as that after `filter` operation the stream will be empty, namely none of its units should be with the same measure name.

In this case `findFirst` will return `Optional.empty()` as stated in its documentation.

The easiest would be doing:

`Mockito.when(uomService.getUnits()).thenReturn(Collections.emptyList()))`

Comment: But `getUnits` is a method of the subject under test, you can't mock that.

Comment: Yes you're right, but since OP posted line `Mockito.when(uomService.getUnits()).thenReturn(Arrays.asList(unitObj));` I've assumed that inside `getUnits()` there is a call to an external service `uomService` that can be mocked. I agree that in general it could be easier if OP could post the `getUnits` Method as well

Comment: getunits is a simple POJO. have updated the code above.

Comment: `getUnits()` is the same as `getUnitLis()`? If so, why do you have a mock `Mockito.when(uomService.getUnits()).thenReturn(Arrays.asList(unitObj));` in the test?

Comment: yes it is the same as getUnitList(). Should i not have it ?

Comment: No, if you don't really call `uomService`. In this case my assumption was wrong

Comment: Please post `getCrsByCode(crsCode)` method as well

Comment: @Mark added sir.

Comment: and `searchCode` method... You should find the place to mimic the response

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203019/discussion-between-arun-and-mark-bramnik).